# How works ajax navigation on jQuery mobile

Tags: ajax, url, jquery-mobile

I have a maybe-noob question for those who know how works jQuery mobile in its core :)

I see on some websites an ajax-like navigation, but with an URL completely changed after load (I mean, no hash at the end).

For example : http://m.wengo.fr/accueil

=> click on any link, you'll see a loader, and after a little animation the new page is loaded ; but the URL has no hash, it's a real new URL.

Is the page really fully reloaded after a first ajax-load behind ?

I don't see how this magic is did on their framework...

Thanks ;)

--
Damien

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather easy implementation.

Page changes should be handled programatically with changePage function (jQuery Mobile 1.4 and below) or pageContainer change (jQuery Mobile 1.4 and above).

### Solution:

```
$.mobile.changePage("second.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
```

What you need is **changeHash** set to **false**.

### Example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
            $(document).on('click', '#open-page', function(){ 
                alert('sdfsd');
                $.mobile.changePage("second.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a class="ui-btn-right" id="open-page">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Second Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

### Update:

Information you need has nothing to do with jQuery Mobile.

I showed you one solution which jQuery Mobile can actually do. But this solution will permanently show original HTML file name. This is because initial HTML page is loaded into the DOM and every other page is loaded into it. jQuery Mobile thus have full control over link name.

But this is not what mentioned page is using. It is using some kind of rewrite engine. By default, rewrite engine maps a URL to a filesystem path. However, it can also be used to redirect one URL to another URL (which is done here), or to invoke an internal proxy fetch.  They are probably using Apache web server with mod_rewrite module turned on.

Comment: My question wasn't "how to use" but "how it works" :/ I'll throw an eye on "changePage" function

Comment: Thanks for the update :) I understand what you mean. But this is not really what I'm asking for. I know there is an URL rewrite on the link I provided. The question is : how jquery mobile does the magic, to redirect to another page AND change the URL on the browser, without any "sharp" (hash), but with an ajax(ajah ?)-like method. I mean, an ajax loading implies a static URL or a variable hash in the browser nav'. Here there isn't any hash, the URL is fully changed, but we can see a preloading and no "blank page" when we are redirected...